# AWS ALB occasional long request_processing_time

Tags: aws-lambda, load-balancing, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an AWS ALB that sends requests to AWS Lambda.

Normally the ***request_processing_time*** is less than 0.01 second and ***target_processing_time*** less than 0.1 second.
However, occasionally the ***request_processing_time*** can take more than 2 seconds. As this only happens once every few weeks, it is quite difficult to reproduce the long latency case.

What might be the root cause? How can I prevent this from happening again?